# Add custom values to Legend in lightningchart

Tags: lightningchart

I can create legends like below:

[image]

Is there any way I can add custom text dynamically in the place of Bollinger band? For example, I want to show live price every second in legend.

Also how do I programmatically enable and disable a legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the legendbox entry returned by the `legendBox.add()` method. This `entry` has a method [`entry.setText()`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/interfaces/legendboxentry.html#settext) that can be used to set the text of the legend box entry to be what ever you want.

```js
const legendBox = chart.addLegendBox()
const entry = legendBox.add(series, undefined, 'Legend Box')

entry.setText('Custom text here')
```

By storing the `entry` reference you can call the `setText` method when ever you want to update the text.

See the below example in which the legend box entry text is updated every time new data is added.

```js
// Extract required parts from LightningChartJS.
const {
  lightningChart,
  DataPatterns,
  Themes
} = lcjs

// Import data-generator from 'xydata'-library.
const {
  createProgressiveTraceGenerator
} = xydata

// Create a XY Chart.
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
  // theme: Themes.dark
})

// Create progressive line series.
const series = chart.addLineSeries({
  dataPattern: DataPatterns.horizontalProgressive
})

const lb = chart.addLegendBox()
lb.setPosition({
  x: 50,
  y: 50
})

const entry = lb.add(series, undefined, 'Legend Box')

// Generate traced points stream using 'xydata'-library.
createProgressiveTraceGenerator()
  .setNumberOfPoints(1000)
  .generate()
  .toStream()
  .forEach(data => {
    series.add(data)
    entry.setText(`Custom text: ${series.getLastPoint().y.toFixed(1)}`)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/xydata@1.4.0/dist/xydata.iife.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@2.2.1/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

You can disable the legend box by calling `legendbox.dispose()`. This will remove the legendbox completely. To then enable the legendbox again you can call `legendbox.restore()` which will restore the legendbox as it was.

Comment: Hi , I actually programatically show and hide the series , like clicking on the custom text !!

Comment: Also How do I hide the title - Legend Box , If I remove it I get Undefined group as title.